# How do I find unique names of songs containing both the words ‘You’ and ‘Me’ from a tibble in R?

Tags: r

I have a tibble with names of artists, track etc. How do I How to I find unique names of songs containing both the words ‘You’ and ‘Me’ from a tibble?

[This is a screen shot of the tibble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoQDJ.png)

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  *Images* of data are particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is your tibble, then:

```
df %>% subset(grepl("You",track,ignore.case=TRUE) &
              grepl("Me",track,ignore.case=TRUE)) %>%
       unique()
```

will output only the unique songs which contain both "You" and "Me" in the track name, and is not case sensitive.

Comment: Sure you cannot reduce the two `grepl` statements to one using `&`?

Comment: Not using `&` AFAIK, but possible like this: `grepl("You.*Me|Me.*You", track, ignore.case = T)`, which may look a little confusing especially if one would want to add extra conditions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
subset(df, grepl("You.*Me|Me.*You, track, ignore.case = TRUE))
```